# MKMapKit iOS 5. Can I set a desired delegate when I want?

Tags: ios

I have a question about map and delegate. I am doing a exercise from a book and it says to me to use the method

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    //CLLocationCoordinate2D loc = [userLocation coordinate];
    self.coord2D = [userLocation coordinate];

    //MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(loc, 250, 250);
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(self.coord2D, 250, 250);

    [worldView setRegion:region animated:YES];
}
```

Which means every time I move my phone from my location it will show myself on screen. I also create a button that calls this method. Therefore if I am scrolling my map I can see where I am.

The problem is: if I am in a car and want to scroll my map it will become a difficult task due this method will be call all the time I change my location.

Is there any other method or if I have an option to activate and deactivate a delegate?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell it's quite simple. Just have a button for activating and deactivating it.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    //CLLocationCoordinate2D loc = [userLocation coordinate];
    self.coord2D = [userLocation coordinate];

    if (self.trackUserLocation) {
        //MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(loc, 250, 250);
        MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(self.coord2D, 250, 250);

        [worldView setRegion:region animated:YES];
    }
}
```

The property:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL trackUserLocation;
```

The button action:

```
self.trackUserLocation = !self.trackUserLocation;
```

You don't have to make it any harder than that.

Comment: What a simple solution. Thanks a lot